# Is it okay to post a bounty to reward a user who should have gotten one, but didn't?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [a question that didn't get an adequate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55823283/why-does-a-pyspark-udf-that-operates-on-a-column-generated-by-rand-fail), so after a while I put a bounty on it.

I later got the answer that I wanted and accepted it, then later realised I didn't award the bounty. I was not paying attention, and awarded the bounty to the *wrong* answer (the inadequate one).

I think that this is unfair, and I would like the person who posted the accepted answer to get the reputation they deserve.

Is it okay for me to set a bounty on another question they have answered to remedy this situation, or, failing that, to set another bounty on my own question for the same purpose? (I realise that that will give them an extra 50 reputation, but better more than less...)

Comment: You can do whatever you want with a bounty, other than award it to one of your own sock puppet accounts.

Comment: props for owning up to it :). But yeah, do what you want with your bounty. If you are to reward ANOTHER answer, I'd say make sure it's a good answer at least... but yeah, no concerns at all

Comment: IMO, it would be *much* better to give the bounty on the same question. Having only one bounty on the question that's given to the inadequate answer sends the wrong signals to future readers. It implies that they should look closely at the answer with the only bounty, because someone felt that it was worth a bounty. Personally, I'd make sure I awarded the new bounty to the accepted answer on that question. I'd probably also leave a brief comment explaining that I mistakenly awarded the first bounty to the wrong answer.

Comment: ... and maybe also make sure the better answer receives a higher bounty, if at all possible. (This is enforced by the site, but I want to focus on the message the bounty sends.)

Comment: first, get 10k, see the horror of all deleted & spam answers, then you'll be glad to lose this privilege again :)

Comment: @Makyen That is what I have done. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to set another bounty if you failed to properly award it the first time. Just pick a reason that tells people that you're rewarding an answer and say in the text box that the bounty is for that answer.

Just remember that your new bounty will have to be for a greater amount than the original one (capped at 500).

Comment: The OP specifically ask about **another question they have answered**, not the same question.

Comment: @Adriaan: They also mentioned "or, failing that, to set another bounty on my own question for the same purpose". It should definitely be this option, not the unrelated-question option.